# On odd integers mod $2q$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Take an odd prime $q$.

Take an odd integer $m$ with $\gcd(m, q) = 1$.

Consider $a$ in $[0, 2q - 1]$ with $am \equiv b \bmod 2q$ where $b$ is odd.

Is $a$ always odd?

Comment: Where are your thoughts and efforts on tackling the question?

Comment: it was a silly problem but wanted to see if there was a way to decouple $2$ from our thinking (silly meaning for example if $b=1$ we have $a$ is inverse mod $m$ and $m$ is inverse mod $a$ and inverse exists only for odd and $q$ coprime integers in $\bmod 2q$) and perhaps there is no way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is, and this has nothing to do with $m$ being coprime with $q$, nor with the range of $a$: we have $$am=b+2kq\quad\text{for some }k\in\mathbf Z$$
so, reducing mod. $2$, we obtain
$$a\cdot 1=a\equiv 1 \mod 2.$$

Comment: No need to take a detour; equivalence mod $x$ automatically follows from equivalence mod $xy$.

Answer (score 1):

Think it out:

Let $m= 2k+1$

Let $b = 2j+1$

$am \equiv b \mod 2q$ means

$am = b + z*2q$ for some integer $z$.

$a(2k + 1) = 2j + 1 + 2zq$

$a = 2j + 1 + 2zq - 2ak = 2(j+2zq - ak) + 1$.

That ... is always odd.

Note: we did *not* have to assume $q$ was prime or that $m$ and $q$ where co-prime.